# SQL pivot and fill in NULL values

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, null, pivot

In SQL (SQLite) I have a table 'weights' containing weights per size of an item e.g.

```
item size    weight
---- ----    ------
 a   small     1.2
 a   medium    2.2
 b   medium    1.6
 c   small     1.0
 c   medium    1.5
 c   large     2.0
```

How can I pivot the table so I have the 'item' column with one row per unique value, then have columns for each value that appears in 'size'. Where a weight isn't present for a given size of an item, a NULL value is inserted instead e.g.

```
item small medium large
---- ----- ------ -----
 a    1.2   2.2   NULL
 b    NULL  1.6   NULL
 c    1.0   1.5   2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select item
      ,max(case when size='small'  then weight else null end) as small
      ,max(case when size='medium' then weight else null end) as medium
      ,max(case when size='large'  then weight else null end) as large
 From weights
 Group By item
```

> **EDIT - Dynamic version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([size]) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [Item],' + @SQL + '
From YourTable
 Pivot (max(weight) For [size] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Note:  I haven't used SQLite in years.  Not sure if this dynamic approach will work

Comment: Looks good! How would I do it if I don't know what values are going to be in the 'size' column? (As currently you've hard-coded them in)

Comment: @user7343733 See EDIT - Dynamic Version

Answer (score 1):

NULL is the result of a CASE when no condition is met.

```
Select      item
           ,max(case when size='small'  then weight end) as small
           ,max(case when size='medium' then weight end) as medium
           ,max(case when size='large'  then weight end) as large
From        weights
Group By    item
```

or

```
Select      item
           ,max(case size when 'small'  then weight end) as small
           ,max(case size when 'medium' then weight end) as medium
           ,max(case size when 'large'  then weight end) as large
From        weights
Group By    item
```